# Hyperion: how do other pilgrims know about Hoyt's cruciforms?

Tags: hyperion-cantos, dan-simmons

*Note: I've read the French version of the books: maybe I'm not using the geniune terminology/names here*

I recently re-read Hyperion by Dan Simmons, and I noticed all pilgrims suddenly know Father Hoyt bears two cruciforms, while I thought this was a secret shared by only the Consul and Hoyt himself.

Right after the Priest's Tale, only the Consul is aware of Hoyt having been fitted with two cruciforms (as the Consul discovers the truth about Hoyt's Tale after Hoyt told it, in his room, and then thinks about what to told the others).
**Unless I missed something**, the Consul never tells his secret to the other pilgrims.
However, later in the same book, after the Tale of Brawne Lamia and before the Consul's one (2 or 3 pages after the begin of chapter 6), **Silenus** says something like: "Hoyt has a cruciform with Father Duré's ghost".

And later, in The Fall of Hyperion, Silenus still knows Hoyt bears two cruciforms (this time, I found the exact English excerpt [here](http://www.eroticvampirenovels.com/read/The-Fall-of-Hyperion-3844/357151) -it's in chapter 8 despite this Website page title):

> "Fucking great. And according to his own story, Hoyt's going to decompose and recompose, thanks to that goddamned cruciform thing... two of the goddamn things, the guy's rich in resurrection insurance..."

Thus my question:
**How do other pilgrims know about Hoyt's cruciforms?**

Answer (score 4):

I think you're right that the other pilgrims are never explicitly told that Hoyt is infected with the cruciform. Descriptions of Hoyt make it clear that his pain is apparent, so perhaps they have all simply guessed on their own that Hoyt is infected, as the Consul did when he saw Hoyt in his room and asked for the true story. How Silenus knows that Hoyt has two cruciforms is not clear.